# Flex Sort is sorting where nothing should be sorted (in an ArrayCollection)

Tags: actionscript-3, sorting, apache-flex, position, swap

I try to sort an arrayCollection with this Sort:

```
    private function sortArray(questions:ArrayCollection):void
    {
        questions.sort = new Sort();
        questions.sort.fields = [new SortField("rank")];
        questions.sort.compareFunction = rankFunction;
        questions.refresh();
    }

    private function rankFunction(a:int, b:int, array:Array = null):int
    {
        if(a == b)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if(a>b)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

There are 23 Objects and all have the rank = 0

I expected that nothing will be changed but after the refresh the items at postion 0 and 11 of the ArrayCollection swapped their position.

In the rankFunction, there is always returned 0.

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

ASDoc [says](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ISort.html#compareFunction) that compare function should have following signature:

```
function [name](a:Object, b:Object, fields:Array = null):int
```

and that the `fields` array specifies the object fields.

So Sort *doesn't* extract field values for you. You should do it yourself.

Concerning your question, it seems that AS3 implicitly converts `Objects` to `ints` invoking `rankFunction`. If so `items` are compared by some internal code that somehow corresponds to the order of items creation.

Comment: Same effect when using this: 

private function sortArray(array:ArrayCollection):void { 
            var sort:Sort = new Sort(); 
            sort.compareFunction = rankFunction; 
            array.sort = sort; 
            array.refresh(); 
        } 

        private function rankFunction(a:Object, b:Object, array:Array = null):int { 
            if(a.rank == b.rank){ 
                return 0; 
            } 
            if(a.rank > b.rank) { 
                return 1; 
            } 
            else{ 
                return -1; 
            } 
        }

Comment: Actually you have only changed `int` for `Object`. My main point was that you should extract fields from object yourself.

Comment: No, that is what I did: if(a.rank == b.rank)

Comment: Solution was using another sort: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1256318?start=0&tstart=0